# How do i use user input floats and find the average, min, max and range in Python

Tags: python

i understand how to do this with integers but im confused about how to take floats from a user and find the average, min, max and range. i keep getting an error message that says: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.

This is my minimal code so far and i know it does not work but just looking for advice on how to take float user numbers and find the average, min, max and range. Thanks!

```
import statistics
def main ():
    
    userNum= float(input("Give me 5 numbers "))
    
    
    average = statistics.mean(userNum)
    print("The average of the numbers given is: ", average)

    print(max(userNum))
    print(min(userNum))

    main()
```

Comment: Try `userNum= [float(x) for x in input("Give me 5 numbers ").split()]`

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly convert the input to float. First you need to split user input. If it is like:

```
"3.4, 5.6, 8.7, 6.4, 9.8"
```

Then try like this:

```
import statistics
def main():
  userNum = float(input("Give me 5 numbers "))
  userNum = [float(x) for x in userNum.split(", ")]
  average = statistics.mean(userNum)
  print("The average of the numbers given is: ", average)

  print(max(userNum))
  print(min(userNum))
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to de-indent `main()` function when calling it, I mean the last line of your code.

This is my solution without `statistics` module because I'm not familiar with it so much.

```
def main():
    tries = 0
    while True:
        tries += 1
        print(f'try number {tries}')
        user_num = float(input('Enter five floating points: '))
        if tries == 1:
            sum1 = user_num
        elif tries == 2:
            sum2 = user_num
        elif tries == 3:
            sum3 = user_num
        elif tries == 4:
            sum4 = user_num
        elif tries == 5:
            sum5 = user_num
            sums = sum1 + sum2 + sum3 + sum4 + sum5
            print(f'sum is {sums}')
            average = sums / tries
            print(f'The average of the numbers given is: {average}')
            all_numbers = [sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4, sum5]
            all_numbers.sort()
            print(f'sorted: {all_numbers}')
            print(f'the minimum number is {all_numbers[-1]}')
            print(f'the maximum number is {all_numbers[0]}')
            break


main()
```

I hope you enjoy it.

Have Fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Update: This is the solution I found. Maybe it is too simplistic but it works for me.

```
def main ():
 import statistics
 userNum= input("Enter 5 floating point values seperated by a space")

 x=[float(x) for x in userNum.split(" ")] #converts string to floating point 
 values

 average = statistics.mean(x) #find the average value entered
 print("The average of the numbers given is: ", average) #print the average 
 number entered

 print (min(x), "The min number given") #print the min number entered
 print (max(x), "The max number given") #print the max number entered


 diff= max(x) - min(x) #calculate the range
 print (diff, "This is the range of numbers given") #print the range


main()
```